# Rename token which is in token list

Tags: phantom, fungible-token

i have created a token thru the old token list github repo.
I need to update the name. I tried with strata (which worked for another token !), but it's not updating (metadata is properly updated, but nor phantom, nor solscan/explorer take the new name/image)
It's a token with 9 decimals.
Do you know if it could be a cache problem, or is there a way to force refreshing the data ?
thanks

**EDIT**

Here is the token address: https://solscan.io/token/FASohke1j5eRAwQBMqTs3W9d3N54xFqNAg3nZRmGKQdk

as you can see in metadata, data are correct

Comment: Hey Frederic! Could you post the token mint hash of the token in question?

Comment: edited my question ;)